# Unable to access element from Sort class c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Hey I am currently doing a homework assignment where we compare different kinds of sorts for efficiency.However I am having trouble accessing a data element and feel slightly dumb because I feel like it should be an easy answer. Here is my main function.

```
    int main()
{
    //declarations
    int const MYARRAYSIZE = 100;
    Sort mySort(MYARRAYSIZE);

    mySort.init_array();

    clock_t timeA = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < MYARRAYSIZE; i++)
    {
        //run tests
        mySort.insertion_sort(/*whatgoeshere*/, MYARRAYSIZE );
    }
    clock_t timeB = clock();
    clock_t diff = timeB - timeA;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

and here is my header

```
class Sort
{
private:
    int size;
    int *myArray;
public:
    Sort(int size);
    ~Sort();
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Sort& s)
    {
        //put code in here
    }
    void insertion_sort(int [], int);
    void selection_sort(int [], int);
    void merge_sort(int [], int);
    void quick_sort(int [], int);
    void partition(int [], int, int&);
    void merge(int [], int, int);
    void init_array();
    int getSize();
};
```

I am trying to access the array that is stored in myArray and I understand that only the class can access it, but how would I go about accessing it?

Comment: If the array is already a member, why is it a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/* whatgoeshere* /`

Nothing goes there.

remove arguments from member functions

Example :

Just use:

`void insertion_sort( );`

This knows its `myArray` and `size` as they are data members of class

And simply call it as

`mySort.insertion_sort( );`

This considers your all member functions are implemented correctly using `myArray` and `size`.

Comment: wow, thanks. I guess I was just really confused because of in the book they had parameters. This all makes sense now. Sorry for the noob question.